# I don't get datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to use the DateTime module and I can never get it to work for this code:

```
class Loan:
    def __init__(self, person_name, bookLoaned, loanStart, loanEnd):
        self.personName = person_name
        self.bookLoaned = bookLoaned
        self.loanStart = datetime.date(loanStart)
        self.loanEnd = datetime.date(loanEnd)
```

For some reason, PyScripter is giving an error "TypeError:an integer is required (got type str)".

I call Loan like this: 
 loan1 = Loan(borrower1.name, BookCopy1.title, ("22/06/2016"), ("22/06/2018"))

I'm expecting it to be some sort of syntax error (which is why I thought it'd only be necessary to post the method and not the entire script)
Can someone please help?

Comment: how do you call `Loan` to begin with

Comment: What is the error?  Please read how to post a [mcve] and edit your question appropriately.  Did you read the documentation for `datetime.date`?  It takes three parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> help(datetime.date)
Help on class date in module datetime:

class date(builtins.object)
 |  date(year, month, day) --> date object
 :
>>> datetime.date(2016,6,22)
datetime.date(2016, 6, 22)
```

`date` doesn't take a string.  Looking at `help(datetime)`, `strptime` sounds like what you want:

```
>>> help(datetime.datetime.strptime)
Help on built-in function strptime:

strptime(...) method of builtins.type instance
    string, format -> new datetime parsed from a string (like time.strptime()).
```

This function takes a string like you want, but also a format.  Let's see what `time.strptime` has to say about formatting:

```
>>> import time
>>> help(time.strptime)
Help on built-in function strptime in module time:

strptime(...)
    strptime(string, format) -> struct_time

    Parse a string to a time tuple according to a format specification.
    See the library reference manual for formatting codes (same as
    strftime()).

    Commonly used format codes:

    %Y  Year with century as a decimal number.
    %m  Month as a decimal number [01,12].
    %d  Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31].
    %H  Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23].
    %M  Minute as a decimal number [00,59].
    %S  Second as a decimal number [00,61].
    %z  Time zone offset from UTC.
    %a  Locale's abbreviated weekday name.
    %A  Locale's full weekday name.
    %b  Locale's abbreviated month name.
    %B  Locale's full month name.
    %c  Locale's appropriate date and time representation.
    %I  Hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number [01,12].
    %p  Locale's equivalent of either AM or PM.

    Other codes may be available on your platform.  See documentation for
    the C library strftime function.
```

So a `datetime` object can be created from a string and an appropriate format:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('22/06/2016','%d/%m/%Y')
datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 22, 0, 0)
```

but you want a `date` only.  Looking back at the help for `datetime.datetime`, it has a `date()` method:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('22/06/2016','%d/%m/%Y').date()
datetime.date(2016, 6, 22)
```

For your code (as an MCVE):

```
import datetime

def date_from_string(strdate):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(strdate,'%d/%m/%Y').date()

class Loan:
    def __init__(self, person_name, bookLoaned, loanStart, loanEnd):
        self.personName = person_name
        self.bookLoaned = bookLoaned
        self.loanStart = date_from_string(loanStart)
        self.loanEnd = date_from_string(loanEnd)

loan1 = Loan('John doe', 'Book Title', "22/06/2016", "22/06/2018")
```